# hay alguna diferencia entre <p> y parrafo sin este elemento?

Tags: html, html5

Si creo por ejemplo un `<div>` y dentro de los tag coloco "el texto de lorum" seria lo mismo que colocar un `<p>` dentro del `<div>` con el mismo texto  ?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rhoncus id augue a ullamcorper. Sed eu purus non nulla ornare feugiat sit amet nec erat. Maecenas quis quam vel lectus dictum varius vitae egestas justo. Integer in fringilla tortor. Donec dictum scelerisque vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In cursus massa vel hendrerit bibendum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depende de lo que para vos signifique "que sea lo mismo". En cortas palabras no es lo mismo y veamos porque:

El **div** es un elemento que sirve como contenedor, en el puedes agrupar elementos.

El **p** es un elemento de párrafo que tiene una finalidad **semántica y estructural**, valga la redundancia , es para escribir párrafos de texto.

Por lo general los navegadores setean valores por defecto a los elementos html, cada navegador aplican los suyos (margin,padding,etc).

Y volviendo a la pregunta , si tu colocas el texto dentro de un tag "p" no es lo mismo que colocarlo solamente en un tag div, ya que contienen un margin, que visualmente va a cambiar su composición.

Te dejo un ejemplo y podes visualizar como la seccion donde se usa un parrafo contiene unos margenes adicionales por default.

```css
div{border:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rhoncus id augue a ullamcorper. Sed eu purus non nulla ornare feugiat sit amet nec erat. Maecenas quis quam vel lectus dictum varius vitae egestas justo. Integer in fringilla tortor. Donec dictum scelerisque vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In cursus massa vel hendrerit bibendum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. <p/>
</div>

<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rhoncus id augue a ullamcorper. Sed eu purus non nulla ornare feugiat sit amet nec erat. Maecenas quis quam vel lectus dictum varius vitae egestas justo. Integer in fringilla tortor. Donec dictum scelerisque vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In cursus massa vel hendrerit bibendum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
</div>
```

Comment: gracias, basicamente la diferencia principal es el margen, pero es recomendable usarr <p>? dentro del navegador seria el mismo efecto mas halla del margen ????? y podria usar un div con margenes para repetir el efecto ? gracias!!!

Comment: Si podrías usarlo sin problemas y agregar estilos al div para visualizarlo como tu quieras. Pero si rozamos muy fino, cada tag html tiene una semántica y una finalidad. Por ejemplo existen el tag nav, que su finalidad es que sea un menu por ejemplo. Vos sabes que en cualquier pagina que veas un tag nav va a contener un menu.  Te dejo un link donde habla mas de html semantico. https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/etiquetas-semanticas-html5.html

Comment: ok entonces usare solo <p> para poder darr mas estilo y que sea mas correcto, gracias, aunque el de abajo dijo que no tiene diferencias ns q onda xddd

Comment: Pero si notas, le agrego solo un background, los margenes son distintos. No cambia mucho visualmente , pero ten encuenta lo que te nombre que es la base de html. Porque es importante para otros tags

Comment: si y tambien no podria agregar id o classs porque no tendria el elemento, gracias! ;D

Comment: le puedes agregar id y class a un tag p igualmente, pero por lo general tienes varios elementos dentro del div y puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera: https://codepen.io/facundofernandez/pen/VrGXWj

Comment: lo que quise decir es que con el p podrias agrregar mas especificamente  a que tipo de texto, y podrias poseer no solo unaa id del div sino tambien del p

Answer (score 1):

**div** - de "division" -división . Sirve para crear secciones o agrupar

El elemento **p** (párrafo) es el apropiado para distribuir el texto en párrafos.
contenidos.

Espero que esto te ayude saludos

```css
div {
background: rgb(72, 172, 150)
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>

  <div class="">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
```

Como puedes ver no hay diferencia entre uno y otro visualmente

Answer (score 1):

La gracia del párrafo es que provee un espaciado natural entre un párrafo y otro (como haría un editor de texto). Si pones todo el texto dentro de un div, los saltos de línea no se reflejarán a menos que los insertes manualmente con un elemento `<br>`

---

Usando `p`

```html
<div>
  <p>
  El presente documento habla sobre la antigua grecia.
  </p>

  <p>
  Grecia era un país. Sigue siendo un país y probablemente seguirá siendo un país.
  </p>

  <p>
  Este ha sido mi ensayo sobre grecia
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Sin usar `p`

```html
<div>
  El presente documento habla sobre la antigua grecia.

  Grecia era un país. Sigue siendo un país y probablemente seguirá siendo un país.

  Este ha sido mi ensayo sobre grecia
</div>
```

Esa es básicamente la diferencia.

Actualmente hay mil maneras de diagramar lo mismo. Puedes hacer un `div` para cada párrafo, o una lista sin bullets, como tú prefieras. Pero en los primeros tiempos de la web, cuando los sitios eran prácticamente documentos de word visibles por internet (texto, tablas, fotos y sería todo...) la diagramación no eran tan flexible como hoy.